# Python 3.3 NameError

Tags: python

```
>>> a=int(input())

2

>>> b=int(input())

4

>>> c=input()

r

>>> if c==r:

    print(b+1)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    if c==r:
NameError: name 'r' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `input()` returns a **string**, so if you want to check if `c` is the string `r`, you have to add double quotes, or single quotes. Both are used to represent strings in Python:

```
if c == 'r':
```

or

```
if c == "r":
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check with `"r"` not `r`. As follows:

```
>>>if c=='r':
>>>    print(b+1)
5
```

This is because when you input "r" it is as a string. When you did the `c==r` you were comparing to the **variable** `r`. This is clearly not what you wanted. Therefore you use `c=='r'` to compare strings.